# Exception throwing and catching in Laravel Module

Tags: php, laravel

I am designing a service based components in Laravel application. The application logic is run on the controller which act as gateway end point . I have many business log created and served through service provider. I doubt how to design the application to handle exception .
For example, if a validation failed, i need to send the message back to the gateway coding . Which is the best method to handle and throw exceptions .  If a validation failed inside a service , the code inside the service can send an exception . The caller / controller has to catch all the type of exceptions then. Is this is the best approach ?

Comment: Validation failure is not **exceptional** case. Laravel lets you validate your requests via `FormRequest` class which is used to define what's required and what isn't. I see no reason why you should throw exceptions at all. Include your `FormRequest` classes for validation, typehint against them in your controller and let Laravel handle the rest. From what I understood, you want to ensure that data is valid before it reaches your code. [Check Laravel's form requests](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#form-request-validation)

Comment: I am not planning to build the application entirely depend on MVC. The caller of the particular service for example a user registration and its related validation will be done by a service through a provider and consumed by a controller. Controller either can pass the result to a view or display as an array/json/object etc . So the result of the operation either success or failure should have a standard format. For the same, i use exception to report a failure case where the caller can catch and format the result accordingly. Hope my idea is expressed here !!

Comment: And in Laravel validation represents an Exception, https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Validation/ValidationException.html   and we retrieve the message from the MessageBag to display !!!

Comment: Considering validation failure is exception is depending on the application design i believe !

Comment: So if you know all of this, why are you asking this question? Failing validation isn't exceptional case. Laravel returns `true` or `false` when validation fails, it simply uses exceptions to reach the error handler in order to render result back to browser. You want to bypass all of that and implement some undefined vision that you have. Since you know all of this - good luck implementing it. Laravel gave you the tools, you don't want them - excellent, build it yourself and best of luck!

Comment: I am seeking help to identify the best practice. While i need to extend the functionality, without affecting the existing code or with minimal changes i have to improve the features. For example, if i want the same service providers and controller logic to use with a presentation layer currently (blade templates) and in future, simply send a json response in future. That time it should be easy to switch . There i think about a standard way to report errors, exceptions, success actions. Surely i need help and good opinions !! Thanks for suggestions !